# Replace @import of google fonts within a css

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a wordpress theme that within one of its CSS files uses the @import function to bring google fonts I would like to replace it in a more optimal way and that fulfills the same functions ....

I leave some code to see if you can help me.

```
@import url (https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900);
@import url (https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700);
.font_weight300 {font-weight: 300! important}
.font_weight400 {font-weight: 400! important}
```

I had thought of doing something like that

```
<link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900" rel = "stylesheet">
```

but that code seems to me that it goes more in an html file for example, but this code with @import goes in a .css file so that's where my doubt goes.

how to best code for css file.

Comment: Within that rule can font-display be used instead of font-face? to be more friendly with browsers?

for example:

@font-display {
    font-family: "CustomFont";
    src: url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the right way to add a font to your project import is for importing a css file if you have the font locally you can put the address in src 
see more about `font-face` on [Mozilla Developers Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: "CustomFont";
        src: url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700");
}
```

and also for using important on a css property you should do this

```
.font_weight400 {font-weight: 400 !important}
```

Comment: MDN is far better than w3fools. `:-)`

Comment: without any doubt :)